# Solved. Q&A: MongoDB MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server. server is remote server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongoose connect to MongoDB fails. But mongo command line can connect to MongoDB.

Code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://192.168.92.131/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

Result:

```
    (node:6559) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [192.168.92.131:27017] on first connect [Error: 

    connect EHOSTDOWN 192.168.92.131:27017 - Local (192.168.92.1:60222)

    at internalConnect (net.js:835:16)

    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:301:12)

    at net.js:926:9

    at processTicksAndRejections
```

(internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {

```
    name: 'MongoNetworkError', errorLabels: [Array],

    [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
```

My MongoDB is installed in a virtual machine running Ubuntu OS. I searched for a solution, but I failed to find a clean solution.

I found a feasible solution to share:

Troubleshooting process

1. Run mongo command line. Connection ok.
2. MongoDB does not have access control (user/password) by default. So my code is ok.
3. IP problem? Mongodb did not start on 192.168.92.131

Google: start mongodb using external ip
Found a solution: https://www.shellhacks.com/mongodb-allow-remote-access/

ether@ubuntu_ether:~$ sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf

No external IP address. So add ip address in mongod.conf

```
…....

    enabled: true

#  engine:

#  mmapv1:

#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.92.131

ether@ubuntu_ether:~$ sudo service mongod restart
```

Run again:
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://192.168.92.131/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});

OK!!!

Comment: Have you tried adding the port?

Comment: If we don't specify the port, it will take the default port 27017. Thanks.